# Display thumbnails for pdf files in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, uiwebview

Hello I'm developing an application which displays a pdf file in `UIWebView`. I want to display the thumbnails of all the pages of pdf files it contains where the user can select his own page he is interested in. I found one sample code to get thumbnails but I'm unable to display it.

```
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSString *fileName= @"2_slo_sample";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL* pdfFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO]];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:request];
webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 480);
webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;

[self.view addSubview:webView];

CGPDFPageRef page;
CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 100); // thumbnail size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfFileUrl);
NSUInteger totalNum = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);

for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ ) {
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);

    // Grab the first PDF page
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i + 1);
    CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, aRect, 0, false);
    // And apply the transform.
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

    // Create the new UIImage from the context
    thumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
```

I'm sure I'm masking some mistake in it. Could you please tell me where I need to get corrected?

Comment: how/where are you setting thumbnailImage in web view??

Comment: im unable to set thumbnailimage in web view...that is the prob im facing could u please guide me to set the thumbnail..

Comment: why are you setting thumbnail in web view, i think you want to to set original image(source image of thumb image) in web view.

Comment: no actually my requirement is to display the pdf file in webview same as the pdf file displayed in the newsstand where the user gets the preview of all the pdf pages in horizontal scroll and he can select his own.in same way i need to display in the UIWebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just above the for loop

```
int x, y, w, h;
x = 5;
y = 5;
```

now in :

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ ) {
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);

// Grab the first PDF page
page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i + 1);
CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, aRect, 0, false);
// And apply the transform.
CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);

CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

// Create the new UIImage from the context
thumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
**[self drawImage:thumbnailImage withX:x withY:y];**
**x = x +100;**
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

}

and method definition as :

```
-(void)drawImage:(UIImage *)image withX:(int)x withY:(int)y
```

{

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.frame =CGRectMake(x, y, **image.size.width**, **image.size.height**);
imageView.image = image;
[self.webView addSubview:imageView];
```

}

ideally you should add pdf thumbnail in view/not in web view (if requirement then its ok)
hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for ur intrest but i have a small prob it is displaying only single image at a time and it is also not so clear....

Comment: yes the same thing i have done except in [self.webview addSubview:imageView] i got some error so i have replaced it by [self->webView addSubview:imageView];

Comment: check my edit, we should not set width and height forcefully to 400.So we can take benefit of UIImage property width and height(the thumbnail you are getting have its width and height, this will make your image look clear).Also make your webView object global variable and just use [webView addSubview:imageView];

Comment: you should add a horizontal scroll view as subview of web view and add  uiimage view with in scrollview, by this if in future you will have say 100 thumbnail image you will be able to look through all image y scrolling

Comment: dude can u send me a code to add web view into horizontal scroll im not getting exact code to it and also for the UIImage view too....

Comment: view - web view -scrollview - imageview simple

Comment: you want me to set UIView in horizontal scrolling then adding webview to uiview and scrollview to webview and then image view into scroll view right...

Comment: add web view as sbview of view, add a uiscrollview/container as subview of web view, add uiimage view as abview of uiscrollview/containr ....